# insert <span> tag in an existing <p> tag with content in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html element

```
<p>The content</p>
```

I would like to add a span around the existing text with jquery

```
<p><span>The content</span></p>
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.wrapInner` at this context,

```
$("p").wrapInner("<span>");
```

This will wrap the content of `paragraph` by a `span` element.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mrtbe699/1/)

Comment: You will probably get away with `$("p").wrapInner("<span>");` but to be safe, the HTML snippet should be well formed - `$("p").wrapInner("<span/>");`

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much

Comment: @NinaPresotto Glad to help! Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer, if you thinks that it helps you solving your issue. And this is not a compulsion. :)